# ActiveRecord query with two associated models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I have two models, `Deal` and `User`. A user `has_many` deals, and a deal `belongs_to` a user (the user who created the deal). Users have the attribute `roles`, where `user.roles` is an array.

I want to find all deals that were created by users whose roles include `"developer"`. I'm used to writing SQL for database queries, so I'm having trouble here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of options:

```
@deals = Deal.select{|d| d.user.roles.include?("developer")}
```

Or

```
@deals = User.select{|u| u.roles.include?("developer")}.map(&:deals).flatten
```

I prefer the first one, but the second one may be quicker depending on how many deals and users you have.

Answer (score 3):

```
@deals = Deal.joins(:users).where(:users => { :roles => ['developer'] })
```

Reference: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

Comment: Hm, I seem to be getting this error when trying this in the rails console:
"ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'user.roles' in 'w
here clause': SELECT `deals`.* FROM `deals` INNER JOIN `users` ON `users`.`id` =
 `deals`.`user_id` WHERE `user`.`roles` IN ('developer')"

Answer (score 1):

I think of myself as a sql caveman, but you can do something like: `Deal.includes(:users).where(:users => {:role => 'developer'})`  or however your user roles are queried.